# Рекурсивный вывод дерева папок

Tags: php, рекурсия

Не могу разобраться с данным алгоритмом:

```
<?php

// Пример печати дерева каталогов файловой системы:

// Функция распечатывает имена всех подкаталогов в текущем каталоге,
// выполняя рекурсивный обход. Параметр $level задает текущую
// глубину рекурсии.
function printTree($level=1) {
  // Открываем каталог и выходим в случае ошибки.
  $d = @opendir(".");
  if (!$d) return;
  while (($e=readdir($d)) !== false) {
    // Игнорируем элементы .. и .
    if ($e=='.' || $e=='..') continue;
    // Нам нужны только подкаталоги.
    if (!@is_dir($e)) continue;
    // Печатаем пробелы, чтобы сместить вывод.
    for ($i=0; $i<$level; $i++) echo "  ";

    // Выводим текущий элемент.
    echo "$e\n";
    // Входим в текущий подкаталог и печатаем его
    if (!chdir($e)) continue;
    printTree($level+1);
    // Возвращаемся назад
    chdir("..");
    // Отправляем данные в браузер, чтобы избежать видимости зависания
    // для больших распечаток.
    flush();
  }
  closedir($d);
}

// Выводим остальной текст фиксированным шрифтом
echo "<pre>";
echo "\n";
// Входим в корневой каталог и печатаем его
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/md1/');
PrintTree();
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

А точнее мне нужно его заставить выводить дерево каталогов не так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так:

Cadillac/Allante/4T60

Cadillac/Allante/4T80E

Cadillac/ATS/6L45E

Все папки имеют по 3 уровня марка/модель/трансмиссия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function printTree($level = -1)
{
    $dir      = '.';
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    if ($level > -1) {
        $iterator->setMaxDepth($level);
    }

    foreach ($iterator as $path => $obj) {
        if ($obj->isDir()) {
            echo $path . '<br>';
        }
    }
}

printTree();
```