# как мне реализовать рекурсивный вывод папок с помощью html+php списка select

Tags: javascript, php, select

всем привет.

хочу реализовать рекурсивный вывод папок с помощью html+php **списка *select***

- т.е. на странице есть 1й список ТОЛЬКО папок корня каталога.
- При выборе в нем нужной папки ниже появлялся бы 2й список с ТОЛЬКО
  подкаталогами,
- если есть еще вложенные папки - ниже 3й список, ну и т.д.
- Если в папке есть еще и файлы, то они просто отобразятся ссылками
  ниже (ну или чем-нить).
- Соответственно, если меняем в 1ом списке что-то, то отобразятся
  только 1й список (корень) и 2й (с вложенными).

вот с чего начал:

2 файла. 1й работает на клиенте, 2й на сервере, пробовал зациклить - наверное глупо. Не пойму как/вернее где ***script*** обрабатывается,

в общем - помогите.

*Geek Brains не предлагать!!!*

Вообще, именно такая реализация - чёто многа кода мне кажется)))

так же не нашел ни чего путнего про **onChange**. в php его, как я понял, не обработать, т.е. скрипты. но вот рассираться из примеров в инете не хочется.
во всем этом (php js html и т.д.)сижу 2 недели.
и да - я читаю, читаю маны)) многое пока не понятно.

*по ходу кода немного вопросов.*     **метод POST предпочтительнее**

**php select-dir.php**

```
<?php
global $x; // надо ли?
$x = 0;// может использоваться как счетчик
// запись в файл $x для out.txt
$fopen = fopen('sel.txt', 'w');
chmod("sel.txt", 0777); // ни чего не говорите про права )))
fputs($fopen,'<?php $dir = $_POST[\''.$x.'\']; $x = '.$x.';?>');
fclose($fopen);

$dir = 'images'; // корневая папка
    $dir_out = @opendir($dir) or die("Ошибка при открытии папки !!!");
    $files = scandir($dir, 0);
    
    $select = '<form id = "sel_dir'.$x.'">';  //привязка формы к скрипту
    // name $x - для вывода в out.php // upIncome() имя функции для скрипта 
    $select .= '<SELECT name ="'.$x.'" onchange="upIncome()">';
    $select .= '<option hidden="none">выбор '.$x.'</option>';
    // не стал использовать WHILE, мне так яснее ситуация
        for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++) {
            $infiles = $files[$i];
            $dir_out = $dir .'/'. $infiles;
                if (is_dir($dir_out)) { //проверяем что это папка
   // на всякий случай колбасим все (вдруг где-то че-то проверять)
                    $select .= '<option name ="'.$infiles.'" value="'.$infiles.'">' . $infiles .'</option>';
                }
        }
    $select .= '</select>';
    $select .= '</form>';
    echo $select;
?>

<!-- здесь вывод -->
<div class="from-server"></div>

<script>
async function upIncome(){
        var x = <?php echo $x ?>;
 <!-- как и что можно сюда добавить? -->
        let response = await fetch('out.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: new FormData(document.querySelector('#sel_dir'+x)),
        });
    ;
 <!-- querySelector - что это?-->
    document.querySelector('.from-server').innerHTML = await response.text();
    }
</script>
```

**php out.php**

```
<?php
global $x; // надо ли?
include 'sel.txt';
echo '<h1>
        папка: '.$dir.'<br>
 // по идее - если б в 1ом файле был бы еще 2й список
 // в той же форме <form id = "sel_dir'.$x.'">
 // то можно было б вывести и его значение <select NAME=""
     </h1>';

// нужно еще как-то $dir менять на $dir/вложенная_дир. массив может ?
?>
```

Comment: есть такой принцип в программировании как "разделяй и властвуй". так что разделите свою задачау на несколько частей и решите каждую в отдельности, затем соедините воедино. Первое - вам нужен код, который по заданной директории получит перечень файлов и папок в ней. Второе - По полученному списку папок и файлов - построит html разметку. Третье - страница на которой это будет отображаться. Просто основной body который обеспечит отправку на сервер ajax запроса для обновления данных при выборке директорий. Где то эти фрагменты нужно разделить на разные файлы, где-то на функции.

Comment: ответ достоин шапки в теме!

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНО**

В общем,прошла неделя... ни кто ни где не ответил, недолгие вечера.. немного манокура *(reading the man)*. Вот, что у меня получилось.
единственное - выпадающий список не добавляется, а обновляется - но к этому и шло.
Для хранения данных используется сессия (для многопользования
*(multiplayer)*). Сразу скажу - не все мне нравится в коде, также часть кода заимствованна [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519715/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba)

главное - работает ))

**select-dir.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // открываем сессию
// проверяем есть ли в ней данные, если нет - то создаем массив 
// и его первый элемент, который является КОРНЕМ
if (!isset($_SESSION['var_array'])) {
    $new = 'открыта еще одна вкладка</br>начата новая сессия';
    $array[0] = 'images';
    $_SESSION['var_array'] = $array;
    $dir = implode('/', $_SESSION['var_array']);
    $_SESSION['var array'] = $array;
      }else{
    $new = '';
    $array = $_SESSION['var array']; // запись сиссии в массив
    $dir = implode('/', $_SESSION['var_array']); //запись массива из сессии в переменную как строка элементов через разделитель(/)
}
echo '<h1><br>папка: /'.$dir.'</br></h1>';
//----------------------------------------------------------
// проверяем валидность папки (пока что таким способом)
    // изменено:
    //$dir_out = @opendir($dir) or die("Ошибка при открытии папки !!!");
    // на
    if (!@opendir($dir)) {
     session_unset(); // удаляем переменные сессии
    // перегружаем скриптом страницу
    echo '<script>location.reload(true);</script>';
    } else { // вывод о новой сессии 
    echo '<h3>'.$new.'<h3></br>
          <h1>папка: /'.$dir.'</h1>';
    }
    //
    // заполняем <select>
    $files = scandir($dir, 0);
    $select = '<form id = "sel_dir">';
// здесь в onchange много функций - в каждую потом можно пихнуть код
// наш главный upIncome()
    $select .= '<SELECT name ="sel" onchange="upIncome(); deleteall(this); log(this);">';
    $select .= '<option hidden="none">выбор из '.$dir.'__'.'</option>';
        for($i = 1; $i < count($files); $i++) {
            $infiles = $files[$i];
            $dir_out = $dir .'/'. $infiles;
// проверка объекта в рекурсии на то что он папка
                if (is_dir($dir_out)) {
                                        $select .= '<option name ="'.$infiles.'" value="'.$infiles.'">' . $infiles .'</option>';
                }
        }
    $select .= '</select>';
    $select .= '</form>';
    echo $select;
echo '</br>';
echo 'мы находимся в   /'.$dir.' =>' ;
echo '</br>';
//----------------------------------------------------------
//заимствовано и изменено
function printTree($level=1) {
  // Открываем каталог и выходим в случае ошибки.
  $d = @opendir('.');
  if (!$d) return;
  while (($e=readdir($d)) !== false) {
    // Игнорируем элементы .. и .
    if ($e=='.' || $e=='..') continue;
    // Нам нужны только подкаталоги.
    if (!@is_dir($e)) continue;
    // Печатаем пробелы, чтобы сместить вывод.
    for ($i=0; $i<$level; $i++) echo "   ";
    // Выводим текущий элемент.
    echo "$e\n";
    // Входим в текущий подкаталог и печатаем его
    if (!chdir($e)) continue;
    printTree($level+1);
    // Возвращаемся назад
    chdir("..");
    // Отправляем данные в браузер, чтобы избежать видимости зависания
    // для больших распечаток.
    flush();
  }
  closedir($d);
}
// Выводим остальной текст фиксированным шрифтом
echo "<pre>";
chdir(getcwd().'/'.$dir);
PrintTree();
echo "</pre>";
// оставляем сессию для записи
session_write_close();
?>
 
<!-- здесь вывод из out.php (но он нам не нужен)  -->
<div class="from-server"></div>
<!-- наша основная функция  -->
<script>
async function upIncome(){
        let response = await fetch('out.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: new FormData(document.querySelector('#sel_dir')),
        });
    ;
  log
    document.querySelector('.from-server').innerHTML = await response.text();
  location.reload(true);

    }
</script>

<!-- еще функция для onchange, то есть их может быть несколько,
эта должна записать в лог браузера выбранный элемент -->
<script>
function log(){ //  запись в лог браузера
  return e => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
}
</script>
```

**out.php**

```
<?php
$dir = $_POST['sel']; // принимаем данные
session_start(); // сессия
//echo 'МОЖНО ВЫВЕСТИ, НО НАМ НЕ НУЖНО
//echo '<h1><br>папка: '.$dir.'</br></h1>';
// проверяем что сессия есть и пишем нужное в сессию
if (isset($_SESSION['var_array'])) { 
    $array = $_SESSION['var_array'];  // забираем из нее данные в массив
if ($dir == '..'){  // если выбрано '..'
    if ($array[1]){ // и присутсвует 2й элемент массива
        array_pop($array); // убираем последний элемент
        $_SESSION['var_array'] = $array; // и пишем в сессию
    }
} else { // иначе
    $array[] = $dir; //  добавляем новый элемент
    $_SESSION['var_array'] = $array; // и пишем в массив
    }
}
// сессию не закрываем
session_write_close();
?>
```

Comment: твою ж дивизию!!! случайно открыл в [новой вкладке .... и .... 
встал вопрос с сессиями](https://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E.15460/)